# angular promise and $http

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, promise

```
ng.module('app')
    .service('CardService', ['$http', CardService])

function CardService($http) {
    this.$http = $http;
    var self = this;

  $http.get('http://localhost:3000/db').success(function(data) {
      self.items = data;
      console.log(self.items);
  });
  console.log(self.items);
}

CardService.prototype.list = function() {
        console.log(self.items);
        return this.items;
};
```

and result

> service.js:14 undefined
>
> service.js:18 undefined
>
> service.js:18 undefined
>
> service.js:12 [Object, Object, Object]

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Stop thinking synchronous. That Ajax request takes time to complete and your code will not hang and wait. Also use .then not .success. Its deprecated.

Comment: [Don't make asynchronous requests inside constructors](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24398699/1048572).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23667086/1048572)

Comment: You should at least mark some answer correct or vote them up.. answering question needs some research... and the ones who answers deserve vote up..

Answer (score 0):

The ajax call is async. It will allow the thread to move on while it waits for a response from the .get

the console.logs you are doing will then be called in this order.

1. `console.log` right below your ajax call
2. `console.log` inside list prototype

(inside ajax success)

3. `console.log` inside list prototype
4. `console.log` below `self.items = data`

Not the angular way, but... the prototype should used only when the list is initialized inside the ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

According to best practices, you should do all the http request related stuff to get data using factory or service. As it is asynchronous flow, $q shall be used to handle it. So your functionality would be done as given below. Kindly correct me if i have misinterpreted your question.

```
app.factory('CardService',function($http,$q) {
var obj = {};

    obj.getCardServiceData = function(){
        var defer = $q.defer();
        $http.get('http://localhost:3000/db').then(function(response) {
         defer.resolve(response.data);
       },function(error){
          defer.reject(error);
       });
       return defer.promise;
    }

    return obj;

});

app.controller('YOUR CONTROLLER',function($scope,CardService){
      CardService.getCardServiceData().then(function(response){
           $scope.self = response.data;
           console.log($scope.self);
       },function(error){
           alert("There seems to be some error!");
           console.error(error);

       });
});
```